# Connecting to Java Server from iPhone Chat application using Socket

Tags: ios, sockets, chat, serversocket

One of my iOS developer is trying to connect to my Chat Application server which is developed using Socket (Java).

When he tries to connect to Server using [GCDAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket) during debug I can see readStreamHeader() is executing which is throwing StreamCorruptedException.

Same thing is happening when I do telnet using cmd : `telnet localhost 13000`

I'm able to connect with my java created client application but not with iOS client. I believe socket in java and in iOS have different way of communication. Please HELP !